# How to save data in JSON format using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have a value and the second one is the model part which is used for storing the data in JSON format. Here `spam_management` is the column in the table in that I have to store like `[{delete:30}]`. `30` is the value taken from the selected option. How can I do that?

```php
public function update_selectedspmlds()
{
  $value = $this->input->post("value");
  $this->approval_model->update_selectedspmlds($value);
}

public function update_selectedspmlds($value)
{   
  $myJson = '{
    "delete": [{
      "lastName": '.$value.'
    }]
  }'; 
  $this->db->insert('pm1cti_details', ['spam_management' => $myJson]); 
}
```

Comment: Do it like this   json_encode($myJson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a JSON and store like `[{delete:30}]`. You need to save the value in a nested array and create a JSON by `json_encode` before saving it to the DB.

```
public function update_selectedspmlds($value) {   
  $myArray = array(
               array(
                'delete' => 30
              )
            );
  $myJson = json_encode($myJson);
  $this->db->insert('pm1cti_details', ['spam_management' => $myJson]); 
}
```